# Kyary Pamyu Pamyu's song: Ninjari Bang Bang

Tags: etymology, song-lyrics

Question to anyone who listens to J-pop-In Kyary Pamyu Pamyu's song にんじゃりばんばん、 what does the りばんばん mean- or where could it have possible came from?

Answer (score 8):

From an [interview](http://natalie.mu/music/pp/kyarypamyupamyu04) with Kyary Pamyu Pamyu:

> ──まず伺いたいんですが、「にんじゃりばんばん」ってどういう意味なんでしょうか？
>
> 私も中田（ヤスタカ）さんに「どういう意味なんですか？」って聞いたんですけど、「俺にもわからない」って言ってました（笑）。だから正解はたぶん誰にもわかんないと思います。

My quick translation:

> Q. First I want to ask, what does "にんじゃりばんばん" mean?
>   A. I also asked Mr. Nakata (Nakata Yasutaka, the person who wrote and produced the song) what it means and he said he doesn't know lol. So probably nobody knows the truth.

She goes on to say how にんじゃりばんばん sounds strange/mysterious (不思議) but cool (カッコいい).